# modify boost::asio::buffer from const char*

Tags: c++, boost

I have `const char*` returning from one function. It reads file and returns const pointer. I am creating `boost::asio::buffer` to send this data using `boost::send_to`. But before sending this buffer I want to modify data inside that buffer. How do I achieve this?

```
std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket> udp_socket;
const char* data_ptr = readFile();
udp_socket->send_to(boost::asio::mutable_buffer(data_ptr, dataSize), endpoint);
```

Comment: `const char*` indicates that the data pointed to is `const` and cannot be modified, is this what's stopping you?

Comment: @kmdreko yes. First is I dont know how to modify buffer. If its plain `C`, I would have just `memcpy()` and sent out the data. I am looking for psuedo code, how to modify buffer and send it to socket.

Comment: `memcpy()` is still an option. If the data is const, you'll have to copy it in order to make modifications, and `boost::asio::buffer` won't do that for you since the buffer types are just (pointer, size) wrappers

Comment: you can use [`buffer_copy`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer_copy.html) to copy data from a `const_buffer` into a `mutable_buffer`, but you have to allocate space for the `mutable_buffer` to use so it wouldn't be much different than a `memcpy` solution.

Comment: @kmdreko so when I call, `send_to` with `boost::asio::buffer(ptr,size)` it will allocate memory for buffer right? so it is one extra copy right? if I use `buffer_copy` then there will be 2 extra copies right? how can I avoid one extra copy?

Comment: `boost::asio::buffer(ptr,size)` does not copy the data, it just references the existing data: "A buffer object does not have any ownership of the memory it refers to" [link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html)

Comment: so I have to use one extra memory using `memcpy` and then I can reference data using `boost::asio::buffer` without extra memory. so in all one extra memory..

Comment: yes, the extra memory is needed if you can't modify what you need to modify. of course if `readFile()` instead returned a mutable data (just `char*`), then you wouldn't have to make the copy.